# Record video in Next js socket io

Tags: next.js, video, socket.io, record, audio-recording

I am building a video  chat web app using next js 14 and socket io, I am looking for a way to record the audio of the call so I can check the recordings to if there is  any problem for my users

I don't have any clue how to do it,
I would like to have guidance on how to do that

Thank you!